# How to write this SQL statement using count and join in Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework

I want to display the results of this `SQL` query in a `WPF` datagrid. My question how to run this query using EF6?

```
select c.*, count(o.id) from clients c
left join optics o
on o.client_id = c.id
where o.r_sph = 12 // 12 is a variable value
group by c.id
```

My Clients model:

```
    public clients()
    {
        this.optics = new ObservableCollection<optics>();
    }

    public long id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> date_of_birth { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime inserted_at { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime updated_at { get; set; }


    public virtual ObservableCollection<optics> optics { get; set; }
```

And Optics model:

```
    public long id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> at { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> r_sph { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> r_axs { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> client_id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime inserted_at { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime updated_at { get; set; }

    public virtual clients clients { get; set; }
```

**Update:**

I use this code to filter the results:

```
public IQueryable < Multi.Model.clients > FilterClients(optisysEntities db, System.Linq.IQueryable < Multi.Model.clients > clients, ClientsFilter clientsFilter) {

 if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientsFilter.Name))
  clients = db.clients.Where(c => c.name.Contains(clientsFilter.Name));

 if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientsFilter.Phone))
  clients = clients.Where(u => u.phone.Contains(clientsFilter.Phone));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to return a new object (unless you already have a model set up which includes the "Count" property). Something like this:

```
var query = (from c in context.Clients
             join o in context.Optics
               on c.id equals o.client_id
            where o.r_sph == 12
            group new { c, o } by new { c.Id } 
             into g
           select new {Id = g.Key.id,
                       // other properties from "Client",
                       Count = g.Count()}
            ).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for the valuable information, I quess I need to dedicate some time to learn EF properly. In the meantime, I see that there are several ways to do things in EF. I have managed to make some filtering on the results using the code above in my updated origianl post, have no clue how to integrate your code into that filteing code. Any input would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Inside ` select new {Id = g.Key.id .. ` I cannot access the Client properties. Any idea what might be wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Each group contains a list so you will need to do `g.First().Property`